# Is there a way to prevent the Screen progarm from killing all windows?

Tags: bash

I have a server application whose output is can be viewed through the Screen application on linux. However, I noticed when using the command-line application I noticed that this command can terminate all windows and close all programs that that window is running in.

Is there a way to prevent a user from using the command to terminate the window, or at least prevent the program the Window program is running under from terminating as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "using the command-line application I noticed that this command"? What command line application? Do you mean screen? What command are you running.  If you are referring to gnu screen logging or detaching could be possible.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are doing the wrong thing...

Is it possible to output the standard out of the program to a file or a pipe and allow access to a cat of that file?

I would also consider looking at the .screenrc and setting a custom file for the session and disabling as much as you can.

Normally server processes are started as a daemon and any "user interface" would be by a socket/command line with the output going to a log file.